# How GBTClassifier deals with unbalanced data for binary classification?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I wanted to perform a binary classification with GBTClassifier on an unbalanced data set. 
I didn't see any option from the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier) allowing to do that.

Does anybody have an idea on how to use GBTClassifier by specifying the fact that our data is unbalanced ?

Thanks

NB: I'm using spark 2.3.2

Comment: if you stick with spark then perform either over-sampling or under-sampling ... in python there are a few more options ... this package https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn can perform something called SMOTE and other class imbalance statistical learning techniques.  If your dataset is small and doesn't need distributed then python libraries contain the more versatile ml approaches

Answer (score 0):

Here is my naive solution: randomly downsampling the majority class.
The drawback of this this solution is the lost of informations and it won't work for small data sets.

```
val resampledTrainDF = {

    val positiveLabel = "1"
    val trainDF_positives = trainDF.where(F.col(label) === positiveLabel)
    val trainDF_negatives = trainDF.where(F.col(label) =!= positiveLabel)

    val withReplacement = trainDF_positives.count >= trainDF_negatives.count

    if (withReplacement) {
        // downsampling positives
        val sampSize = math.round(  (1.0 * trainDF_negatives.count / trainDF_positives.count) * 1000) / 1000.0
        println("Downsampling Positives by " + (1 - sampSize)*100 + " %")
        trainDF_positives.sample(false, sampSize).union(trainDF_negatives)
    } else { 
        //downsampling negatives
        val sampSize = math.round(  (1.0 * trainDF_positives.count / trainDF_negatives.count) * 1000) / 1000.0
        println("Downsampling Negatives by " + (1 - sampSize)*100 +  "%")
        trainDF_negatives.sample(false, sampSize).union(trainDF_positives)
    }

}
```